# MATLAB plotting error

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I am trying to plot the following function:

[image]

The time interval is to be from  0 to 5 seconds using a step size of 0.002.
This is what I have so far...

```
t = 0:0.002:5;
k = [2; 4; 6; 8];
i = (1/pi) + 0.5*sin(4*t) - (2/pi)*sum((cos(4*k*t))/(k*k-1));
plot(t,i)
```

It gives me the error:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in lab1_5 (line 4)
i = (1/pi) + 0.5*sin(4*t) -
(2/pi)*sum((cos(4*k*t))/(k*k-1));
```

I then tried every use of './' and '.*' but it still gives me the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
t = 0:0.002:5;
k = [2; 4; 6; 8];

i = (1/pi) + 0.5*sin(4*t)
for j=1:4
    i = i-(2/pi)*((cos(4*k(j)*t))/(k(j)*k(j)-1));
end
plot(t,i)
```

The reason is that `k` is a col-vector (or a 4x1 matrix), so you cannot simply multiply it by `k*k`. For matrix multiplication, the size of left and right must follow `n × m` and `m × p`. In this case, you need to loop multiply every elements of `k`.

Comment: You are not handling the multiple indexing at all in your answer.  k'*k is a constant!  That whacks the sum.

Comment: Ah that's it, thank you. Just wondering, if k is a row vector, what then should I do?

Comment: You're getting closer.  The size of your summands is 1,1, not 1,2501 which is how you're treating it.  You don't need the "sum" term, that's whacking your results (still)

Comment: @John Yeah, too careless for me. Fixed and thanks. :)